# Unable to hit API endpoints with GET

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working on building an API for handling identity stuff in .NET Core, but every time I try and make a call I get a 404.

There didn't seem to be anything clear when I looked around for an answer, since the code posted seems quite minimal. Here's all the stuff I think is pertinent.

The Controller:

```
using Common.Extensions;
using Identity.Database.Contexts.Models;
using Identity.WebApi.Models;
using Identity.WebApi.Models.Tokens;
using Identity.WebApi.Services.Access;
using Identity.WebApi.Services.Accounts;
using Identity.WebApi.Services.Tokens;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Controller = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller;
using Get = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpGetAttribute;
using Post = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpPostAttribute;
using Route = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RouteAttribute;

namespace Identity.WebApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class IdentityController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IApplicationUserService _userService;
        private readonly IAccessService _accessService;
        private readonly ITokenService _tokenService;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;

        public IdentityController(IApplicationUserService userService, IAccessService accessService, ITokenService tokenService, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
        {
            _userService = userService;
            _accessService = accessService;
            _tokenService = tokenService;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }

        [Get]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public string Index()
        {
            return new Dictionary<string,string>
            {
                { "status", "live" }
            }.Serialize();
        }

        [Post]
        [Route("create")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public Task<ISet<IdentityResult>> Create(string user)
        {
            var decodedUser = DecodeUser(user);

            var applicationUser = new ApplicationUser(new User
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Name = decodedUser.Username,
                LastActive = DateTime.UtcNow
            });

            return _userService.Add(applicationUser, decodedUser.Password);
        }       

        private (string Username, string Password) DecodeUser(string encodedUser)
        {
            var decodedUser = encodedUser.DecodeFrom64().Split(':');
            return (Username: decodedUser[0], Password: decodedUser[1]);
        }

        private async Task<bool> CheckPasswordAsync(ApplicationUser user, string password)
            => await _signInManager.UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password);
    }
}
```

The Startup:

```
using Identity.Database.Contexts;
using Identity.Database.Contexts.Access;
using Identity.Database.Contexts.Extensions;
using Identity.Database.Contexts.Models;
using Identity.WebApi.Models;
using Identity.WebApi.Services.Access;
using Identity.WebApi.Services.Accounts;
using Identity.WebApi.Services.Certs;
using Identity.WebApi.Services.Tokens;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Identity.WebApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton(new CertService(Configuration) as ICertService)
                .AddTransient<IApplicationUserService, ApplicationUserService>()
                .AddTransient<IApplicationRoleService, ApplicationRoleService>()
                .AddTransient<IAccessService, AccessService>()
                .AddTransient<ICertService, CertService>()
                .AddTransient<ITokenService, TokenService>()
                .AddTransient<ICrudDao<AppDbContext, Role>, RoleDao>()
                .AddIdentities<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
                .AddScoped<UserManager<ApplicationUser>, UserManager<ApplicationUser>>()
                .AddScoped<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>, SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>()
                .AddScoped<RoleManager<ApplicationRole>, RoleManager<ApplicationRole>>()
            .AddMvc();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.Use(async (c, n) =>
            {
                await n();

                if (c.Response.StatusCode == 404)
                {
                    c.Request.Path = "/identity";
                    await n();
                }
            });

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseAuthentication();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseMvc(r => { r.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=identity}/{action=Index}"); });
        }
    }
}
```

The launch settings:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:55048/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/identity/index",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "WebApplication1": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/identity/index",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:55048/"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you include the route you are trying to hit that's returning the 404?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of your controller you have:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class IdentityController : Controller
```

Which means that if your route starts with `api/` only then it will match the controller. Also, your Index action doesn't have any extra routing attributes on it, so its looking for `api/identity` only. However, your launch settings don't match that part, and since you don't have any other routes matching it, you get a 404.

The default route in `app.UseMvc` won't work for this reason.

Simple fix: change `launchUrl` to just `api/identity` in your launch settings... and then follow @Nkosi's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48573245/3419825)

Comment: oh... Thanks @Nkosi I missed that. I think you're right - the launch settings just need to be updated to `api/identity`

Comment: Yeah, this one got me unstuck. I'm now getting through to the controller and seeing the dependency injection errors I expected (first time doing this in .NET Core).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If using attribute routing then there is no `api/identity/index` as `[HttpGet]` or `Get` in your example with a route prefix, is the same as

```
[Get] //<-- Matches GET api/identity
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Index() {
    var result = new Dictionary<string,string>
        {
            { "status", "live" }
        }.Serialize();
    return Ok(result);
}
```

And since this appears to be a Web API that is not expected to return a View then the `Http{Verb}` attribute with a route template would be the option to use for routing

> When building a REST API, it's rare that you will want to use `[Route(...)]` on an action method. It's better to use the more specific `Http*Verb*Attributes` to be precise about what your API supports. Clients of REST APIs are expected to know what paths and HTTP verbs map to specific logical operations.

```
[Post("create")]  //<-- Matches POST api/identity/create
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(string user) {
    var decodedUser = DecodeUser(user);

    var applicationUser = new ApplicationUser(new User
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Name = decodedUser.Username,
        LastActive = DateTime.UtcNow
    });

    ISet<IdentityResult> result = await _userService.Add(applicationUser, decodedUser.Password);
    return Ok(result);
}
```

Reference [Routing to Controller Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)